# how to create ambari database backup without enter password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pg-dump

We configure the file `.pgpass` as follows in order to create database backups without entering a password:

```
-bash-4.2$ more .pgpass
localhost:5432:postgres:ambari:bigdata
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql
-bash-4.2$ whoami
postgres
-bash-4.2$ more .pgpass
localhost:5432:postgres:ambari:bigdata
-bash-4.2$
```

But after that still `pg_dump` insists to enter the password - why?

Where am I wrong?

```
pg_dump -U  ambari  -f ambari.sql
Password:
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to connect to a database called `ambari` this way (when specifying only the `-U` parameter, the DB name is taken from its value).

From the `.pgpass` file it looks you want to connect to the `postgres` DB.  Specify `-d postgres`, too, or set

```
localhost:5432:*:ambari:bigdata
```

in your `.pgpass` file.  (As it turns out, there is an `ambari` DB, so the connection parameters look all right.)

Note that by default this file has to be in the OS user's (in this case `postgres`) home directory.  Alternatively, you can [specify its location](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) in other ways.